# box2d tick function doesn't work

Tags: box2d, easeljs

I'm new to game developement with javascript and I'm following a tutorial where easeljs and box2d are used to create a bouncing ball.
I wrote the same code as shown in the video tutorial, but the ball is not animated

```
(function(window){      
function Ball(){                    
    this.view = new createjs.Bitmap("soccer.png")
    this.view.regX = this.view.regY = 50;

    var fixDef = new box2d.b2FixtureDef();
    fixDef.density = 1;
    fixDef.friction = 0.5;
    fixDef.restitution = 0.8;
    var bodyDef = new box2d.b2BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = box2d.b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.x = Math.random()*800 / SCALE;
    bodyDef.position.y = 0;
    fixDef.shape = new box2d.b2CircleShape(50 / SCALE);
    this.view.body = world.CreateBody(bodyDef);
    this.view.body.CreateFixture(fixDef);
    //this.view.addEventListener("tick", tick); 
    this.view.onTick = tick;        
}

function tick(event){       
    this.x = this.body.GetPosition().x * SCALE;
    this.y = this.body.GetPosition().y * SCALE;
    this.rotation = this.body.GetAngle() * (180/Math.PI);
}
window.Ball = Ball;
})(window);
```

it appeas that the `this.view.onTick = tick;`   not working so I changed it to `this.view.addEventListener("tick", tick);`
and now this gives an error `this.body` is undefined

Answer (score 1):

problem solved I used `this.view.on("tick", tick, this.view);`

Comment: Yep, just a loss of scope. You could also do: `this.view.addEventListener("tick", this.tick.bind(this));` -- Note that to remove the listener added with `on`, you need to store and remove the closure generated by the `on` function. Passing the `tick` function to `off` will not work. Cheers.